# Genetic Algorithm to find best parameter values of an estimaor

Tags: optimization, hyperparameter, genetic-algorithms

I am making some stochastic training ensemble classes in Python, and I want to get hyperparameters values. Grid search will take too long for moderate data sets, because in my stochastic training I train different learners on different dropouts, as in cross-validation, then I average or weight-average on best error for dropout. Having this set, I want to get best parameter values at every iteration, so I thought to use a genetic algorithm approach.

I found one example on Github, but failed to install, and I am looking for more references of genetic algorithms for doing this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try using R? Here is an example: http://www.r-bloggers.com/genetic-algorithms-a-simple-r-example/
I also agree with the answer below. Writing your own code to do a simple GA wouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: There is another R package called "GA" which I use from time to time, despite my answer below :)  It has the advantage of [excellent documentation](http://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v053i04/v53i04.pdf) with many examples.

Answer (score 2):

Having used genetic algorithms extensively in both professional projects and for my own entertainment, I think it is best to just code your own set of functions/classes for the specific project.  As you have seen, there are quite a few well-intended open-source GA packages out there. However, many of the fine details and tweaks necessary for a good GA are problem-specific.  It is also more convenient to work directly with your existing data structures, rather than adapt to someone else's worldview.  In other words, cost-benefit does not seem to work out when applying someone else's GA package.  You need a function for creating a random instance, a function for checking it is valid, a function for scoring it, and a mating function.  That's pretty much it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know details of algorithm itself, but if you are using Python this module could help you:

https://epistasislab.github.io/tpot/

I'm using it, and it seems to work nicely.